# Inconsistent results of certificate chain verification

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509

I am getting inconsistent results of certificate chain verification with different OpenSSL libraries. The chain is verified successfully on MacOS using `LibreSSL 2.8.3` and fails on Linux machine with `OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018`. Command used for verification:

```
$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile <(cat certificate_3.pem certificate_2.pem certificate_1.pem) certificate_0.pem
```

`certificate_0.pem` is the leaf certificate.

Result on MacOS (`LibreSSL 2.8.3`):

```
certificate_0.pem: OK
```

Result on Linux (`OpenSSL 1.1.1`):

```
serialNumber = (…omitted…)
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
serialNumber = (…omitted…), title = (…omitted…)
error 24 at 2 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
error certificate_0.pem: verification failed
```

I suspect differences in libraries implementation - the intermediate certificates (certificate_2.pem and certificate_1.pem) in the chain do not appear to have the **basicConstraints** and **keyUsage** X509 extensions.

I would wish to verify the chain successfully with OpenSSL 1.1.1. Please advise how to do it despite missing X509 extensions.

EDIT: I've also tried:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile certificate_3.pem -untrusted <(cat certificate_2.pem certificate_1.pem) certificate_0.pem
```

as suggested by @garethTheRed in comment, but it still fails.

Comment: You should only have the trust-anchor in the file pointed to by `-CAfile`.  All other CA certificates should be pointed to by `-untrusted`.  However, I believe you'll still fail to verify if the intermediate CA certificates don't have the required extensions.

Comment: Could you show what is the value of the basicConstraints in the certificate_3.pem? You can get the value using the following command `openssl x509 -in certificate_3.pem -noout -text`.

Comment: Check this paragraph in the RFC5280 about the basicConstraints extension: `The cA boolean indicates whether the certified public key may be used to verify certificate signatures.  If the cA boolean is not asserted, then the keyCertSign bit in the key usage extension MUST NOT be asserted.  If the basic constraints extension is not present in a version 3 certificate, or the extension is present but the cA boolean is not asserted, then the certified public key MUST NOT be used to verify certificate signatures.`